# ttlSecondsAfterFinished for SCDF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

Whats the SCDF equivalent property for spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished which is used in Kubernetes for JOb cleanup?
I couldn't find the exact documentation for this property. Could anyone point to the proper documentation?

Answer (score 1):

SCDF doesn't have this `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` property support yet. But, I see that this is an [alpha feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/) and not yet promoted.